# Why aren't conda commands working in Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

I recently downloaded Spyder using Python 3.9.12. For some reason, every time I try to use a conda command (such as conda activate env), the Spyder terminal gives the message 'Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.' I've restarted the kernel multiple times, but the same message persists, essentially meaning that I cannot use conda commands in Spyder. However, they work fine in the regular Anaconda3 prompt. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Our IPython console is not meant to run `conda` commands on it, nor it works in cases like `conda activate`. If you want to install packages on your environment, please open the Anaconda Prompt and run `conda` there. But if you want to connect Spyder to different envs, please read [our docs](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) about that.